# python tkinter Monty Hall GUI visualization

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, tkinter

I created a visualization to Monty Hall with python. this is my first program with python tkinter. I'm new to python (and OOP in python). I used three pictures for the doors. Adding them here.

download the doors gifs - https://ufile.io/2h7fb

Or, download separately:

door1.gif - https://ibb.co/jSNntw

door2.gif - https://ibb.co/bTCntw

door3.gif - https://ibb.co/bs0U6G

Would love to get some review. I'm sure my object oriented skills are not good at the moment.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Button, PhotoImage
import random


DOOR_1 = 1
DOOR_2 = 2
DOOR_3 = 3
DOORS = (DOOR_1, DOOR_2, DOOR_3)


class MontyHall(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.total_counter = 0
        self.winning_switchers = 0
        self.winning_non_switchers = 0
        self.geometry("600x600")
        self.title("Monty Hall")
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=600, height=500)
        self.text = self.canvas.create_text(300, 120)
        self.answer = self.canvas.create_text(300, 140)
        self.text_switching = self.canvas.create_text(300, 30)
        self.text_not_switching = self.canvas.create_text(300, 60)
        self.door1_pic = PhotoImage(file='door1.gif')
        self.door2_pic = PhotoImage(file='door2.gif')
        self.door3_pic = PhotoImage(file='door3.gif')
        self.door1_show = self.canvas.create_image(100, 350, image=self.door1_pic)
        self.door2_show = self.canvas.create_image(300, 350, image=self.door2_pic)
        self.door3_show = self.canvas.create_image(500, 350, image=self.door3_pic)
        self.canvas.grid(row=2, sticky='s')
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.door1_show, "<Button-1>", self.door1)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.door2_show, "<Button-1>", self.door2)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.door3_show, "<Button-1>", self.door3)

    def door1(self, *args):
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.text, text="you chose door number 1")
        self.choose_door(DOOR_1)

    def door2(self, *args):
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.text, text="you chose door number 2")
        self.choose_door(DOOR_2)

    def door3(self, *args):
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.text, text="you chose door number 3")
        self.choose_door(DOOR_3)

    def choose_door(self, door_chosen):
        self.block_doors(4)
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.answer, text="")
        correct_door = random.choice(DOORS)
        if correct_door != door_chosen:
            close = random.choice(list(set(DOORS) - {correct_door, door_chosen}))
        else:
            close = random.choice(list(set(DOORS) - {door_chosen}))
        self.block_doors(close)
        self.options(door_chosen, correct_door, close)

    def block_doors(self, block_door_number):
        if block_door_number == 4:
            self.canvas.tag_unbind(self.door1_show, "<Button-1>")
            self.canvas.tag_unbind(self.door2_show, "<Button-1>")
            self.canvas.tag_unbind(self.door3_show, "<Button-1>")
        if block_door_number == 3:
            self.canvas.delete(self.door3_show)
        elif block_door_number == 2:
            self.canvas.delete(self.door2_show)
        elif block_door_number == 1:
            self.canvas.delete(self.door1_show)

    def unhide_door(self, open_door):
        if open_door == 1:
            self.canvas.tag_bind(self.door2_show, "<Button-1>", self.door2)
            self.canvas.tag_bind(self.door3_show, "<Button-1>", self.door3)
            self.door1_show = self.canvas.create_image(100, 350, image=self.door1_pic)
            self.canvas.tag_bind(self.door1_show, "<Button-1>", self.door1)
        if open_door == 2:
            self.canvas.tag_bind(self.door1_show, "<Button-1>", self.door1)
            self.canvas.tag_bind(self.door3_show, "<Button-1>", self.door3)
            self.door2_show = self.canvas.create_image(300, 350, image=self.door2_pic)
            self.canvas.tag_bind(self.door2_show, "<Button-1>", self.door2)
        if open_door == 3:
            self.canvas.tag_bind(self.door1_show, "<Button-1>", self.door1)
            self.canvas.tag_bind(self.door2_show, "<Button-1>", self.door2)
            self.door3_show = self.canvas.create_image(500, 350, image=self.door3_pic)
            self.canvas.tag_bind(self.door3_show, "<Button-1>", self.door3)

    def options(self, door_number, correct_door, closed_door):
        self.total_counter += 1

        def show_results():
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.text_switching,
                                   text='Switching won {0:5} times out of {1} ({2:.2f}% of the time)'
                                   .format(self.winning_switchers, self.total_counter,
                                           (self.winning_switchers / self.total_counter * 100)))
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.text_not_switching,
                                   text='Not switching won {0:5} times out of {1} ({2:.2f}% of the time)'.
                                   format(self.winning_non_switchers, self.total_counter,
                                          (self.winning_non_switchers / self.total_counter * 100)))

        def change(*args):
            button1.grid_forget()
            button2.grid_forget()
            chosen_door = next(iter(set(DOORS) - {door_number, closed_door}))
            if chosen_door == correct_door:
                self.canvas.itemconfig(self.answer, text="you were right")
                self.winning_switchers += 1
            else:
                self.canvas.itemconfig(self.answer, text="you were wrong")
            self.unhide_door(closed_door)

        def keep(*args):
            button1.grid_forget()
            button2.grid_forget()
            if door_number == correct_door:
                self.canvas.itemconfig(self.answer, text="you were right")
                self.winning_non_switchers += 1
            else:
                self.canvas.itemconfig(self.answer, text="you were wrong")
            self.unhide_door(closed_door)

        button1 = Button(self, text='Click to change door')
        button1.bind("<Button-1>", change)
        button1.grid(row=0, sticky='w')

        button2 = Button(self, text='Click to keep door')
        button2.bind("<Button-1>", keep)
        button2.grid(row=1, sticky='w')
        show_results()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = MontyHall()
    application.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overview

You've done an excellent job:

- Overall code layout is good
- You did a good job partitioning code into functions
- You leveraged code written by others with the imports
- Used meaningful names for classes, functions and variables

Here are some adjustments for you to consider, mainly for coding style.

### Documentation

Add comments at the top of the file to state the purpose of the code.  For example:

```
'''
Monty Hall problem.
Here's how it works... add summary here
'''
```

### Instructions

When I run the code, all I see is three doors.  I don't know what I am expected to do.
You should display some simple instructions in the GUI to prompt the user
for expected actions, such as:

```
Click on one of the doors to blah, blah, blah...
```

### Efficiency

In the `unhide_door` function, it is wasteful to check the value of the `open_door`
variable in three separate `if` statements.  They can be combined into a single `if/elif`:

```
    if open_door == 1:
        // ...
    elif open_door == 2:
        // ...
    elif open_door == 3:
```

You partially did this in function `block_doors`.  However, you should merge
the two `if` statements into one `if/elif`.

### Simpler

Consider removing these constants; it might be simpler just to use the numbers themselves:

```
DOOR_1 = 1
DOOR_2 = 2
DOOR_3 = 3
```

### [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

There are a lot of instances where the the code is repeated 3 times, once
for each door.  Although I don't have a specific recommendation in mind,
it would be worth spending some time looking for an opportunity to combine
common code.